# Unable to implement Load More in Listview using AsyncTask android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, fetch

I implemented a `ListView` with a "load more" `Button` and it works fine when the data is picked from the local database.

At the start of the `Activity`, the first 20 elements are fetched using `AsyncTask`. After that when "load more" `Button` is pressed the data has to be again fetched using a server call. But as soon as the server call is initiated using `AsyncTask` it shows an error that the `AsyncTask` has already been excuted once and it cant be executed twice.

I checked the documentation and it says that `AsyncTask` is executed only once. Then what option do I have to make multiple server calls to append in my `ListView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new instance of your `AsyncTask`

```
private void loadSomeData() {
    MyTask task = new MyTask();
    task.execute();
}

privat void loadMore() {
      MyTask task = new MyTask();
      task.execute();
}
```

Obviously, there are different ways to do it but that's to give you the idea.

What you can't do is create an instance of your task and reuse it...

```
public class MyClass extends Activity {

    MyTask task = new MyTask();

    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        ...
        task.execute()
    }

    private void loadMore() {
        task.execute();
    }
}
```